# How to hide/remove "Area" name in URL ASP.NET MVC (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have created an application using 'Area' based on the user role. Have 3 areas Admin,  Approver and Submitter. If the clicks a links, its showing area name in URL. I don't want to show the Area name in URL. How to achieve this? (MVC with ASP.NETCORE)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not remove `Area Name` from generated URL. `Area Name` is used to indicate where to find the Controller. eg, if you follow [Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.1), it will have multiple different `HomeController` in dfferent `Area`. Without area name, it will not able to redirect to the specific Controller with `Home/Index`.

For changing the route for controller in area which will also generate the URL without area name, you could try `Route` attribute.

For example, I have a `AdminController` with `[Route("AdminIndex")]`

```
    [Area("Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [Route("AdminIndex")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Code For URL.

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Index">Admin Index</a>
```

URL Result.

```
<a href="/Index">Admin Index</a>
```